# nodejs: 'AppAside' is not exported from '@coreui/react'

Tags: node.js, core-ui

Latest Version: `"@coreui/coreui-pro": "^4.0.4",`

Current Version: `"@coreui/coreui-pro": "^2.1.14",`

After upgrading, I got this error.`'AppAside' is not exported from '@coreui/react'`

What to do?

Comment: They have renamed all component name in updated version, you can import now as `CSidebar`, `CFooter`, `CHeader`